# What is $H^1([0,1]) \otimes H^1([0,1])$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces, tensor-products

Let $H^1([0,1])$ denote the Sobolev space $H^1$ on the interval $[0,1]$. What is
$H^1([0,1]) \otimes H^1([0,1])$?

Here, $\otimes$ the tensor product of Hilbert spaces. In particular, how is that object related to $H^1([0,1]^2)$?

Comment: [It's a dense subspace](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/441536/).