# Prove that $F$ is dense in $C(X\times Y,\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: analysis, matrices, functional-analysis

Let $X$ and $Y$ be compact metric spaces. Let
$$
F= \Bigl\{\sum_{i=1}^n A_i f_i(x) g_i(y): f_i\in C(X,\mathbb{R}),g_i\in C(Y,\mathbb{R}), 1\le i\le n \Bigr\}.
$$
Prove that $F$ is dense in $C(X\times Y,\mathbb{R})$.

Please, I can't figure it out.

I will be thankful for any help.

Comment: this is difficult to read, I suggest that you edit this post to make it more legible.

Comment: what about now ? this is the first question for me and i have so much trouble to make it.

Comment: You probably meant to say that $A_i\in {\bf Q}$ or $A_i\in{\bf R}$.

Comment: Also, this question (which is on top of the related questions on the right hand side!) is kind of a generalisation of your question, and contains a possible hint for you. http://math.stackexchange.com/q/63416/30222

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Stone-Weierstrass theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem).

Comment: can you help me step by step.. i have problem with this chapter

Comment: Compact+Hausdorff $\implies$ normal $\implies$ $C(X,\mathbb{R})$ separates points in $X$, $C(Y,\mathbb{R})$ separates points in $Y$. Take $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)\in X\times Y$ with $(x_1,y_1)\ne(x_2,y_2)$. Suppose wlog that $x_1\ne x_2$. Now, construct a separating function $\in F$.